# Optimization: Gradient of constraints - How to solve in a quadratic formula?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, quadratic-programming

Assume that we have our objective function (matrix algebra)

$$J(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T Q x + c^T x$$

With the constraints:

$$lb \le x \le ub \\
lba \le Ax \le uba$$

I begin first to determine how large $x$ can be. So I will first use these constraints first.
$$x \le ub \\
Ax \le uba$$

We concatenate these into one constraints $g(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
x & -ub & \\ 
Ax & -uba & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

The second thing I need to do is to find the gradient of $J(x)$ which is the derivative respect on $x$:

$$\triangledown J(x) = x^T Q + c^T$$

And the same for $g(x)$

$$\triangledown g(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 &  & \\ 
A &  & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now I need to put $\triangledown J(x) = \lambda \triangledown g(x)$ and find the $x$

But the problem is that $\triangledown g(x)$ has twice the dimension of $\triangledown J(x)$

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\nabla J(x) = \lambda \nabla g(x)$, both sides are of dimension $x$. But there is a more fundamental problem: that equation alone does not solve the problem. What you need are the KKT conditions (neccessary and sufficient if $Q$ is positive semidefinite). Define the Lagrangian
$$L(x,\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4) = 0.5 x^TQx + c^Tx + \lambda_1^T(x-u) + \lambda_2^T(l-x) + \lambda_3^T(Ax-u_A)+\lambda_4^T(l_A-Ax).$$
The stationarity condition w.r.t. $x$ is what you tried to derive:
$$Qx + c + (\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) + A^T (\lambda_3 - \lambda_4) = 0$$
The other KKT conditions are complementary slackness:
$$\lambda_1^T(x-u) = 0, \;\lambda_2^T(l-x) = 0, \;\lambda_3^T(Ax-u_A) = 0,\; \lambda_4^T(l_A-Ax)=0$$
and primal/dual feasibility:
$$l \leq x \leq u, \; l_A\leq Ax\leq u_A, \; \lambda_1\geq 0, \;\lambda_2\geq 0, \;\lambda_3\geq 0, \;\lambda_4\geq 0.$$
Finding a solution that satisfies all these conditions is not easy. I recommend using a QC(Q)P solver such as CPLEX/Gurobi/Mosek (commercial) or Ipopt (free).

Comment: Thank you! Good answer! If I want to have constraints only on $Ax$? Can I do that with just an if-statement and a for-loop? Simple optimization.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson equality constraints are easy, inequality constraints are hard (and require the QCQP solver).

Comment: Ok. If I compute the equality constraints and then use an if-statement to check if the vector $x$ is to large or to small? https://pastebin.com/9dpxjxHe

Comment: @DanielMårtensson unfortunately it is not that simple. If you use matlab, why not use quadprog? You could also write a small interior point solver with just 25 lines of code.

Comment: I'm trying to convert all that into C code by hand. It's for embedded systems.

Comment: a simple interior point solver is 25 lines of C code if you can use a linear algebra subroutine for doing cholesky and triangular solves.

Comment: Interesting. So if I write an  interior point solver in C, I can have constraints on...Ax only? Or x? Or both? I don't require high accuracy.

Comment: Both. If you don't care about accuracy at all you can look into ADMM as well. Simple implementation, but solutions can be far off.

Comment: Hmm ADMM seems to be advanced. I need something simple. I found some code for ADMM and it looks like it was difficult.